# Server program that listens on two different socket interfaces

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcpserver

Is it possible that a TCP server program can listen on two different socket interface?

**Problem Statement:**

I've a problem statement where the TCP server will be having two interfaces:

- Interface I: For accepting generic data from TCP client (IP address 192.168.5.10:2000)
- Interface II: Management Interface for the server (IP address 192.168.5.11:2000)

Interface I: This interface shall receive data from TCP client, processes them & send it back to client.

Interface II: This interface shall receive commands (meant for Servers management purpose). This commands most probably would be sent through telnet.

**Current Status:** 
I already have a **thread based TCP server** program where I've "**Interface I**" up & running(I'm able to receive data from multiple clients, process them & send it back)

Can anyone give me some pointers/prototype example on how to add **"Interface II"** to my TCP server program?

NOTE: TCP server program is written in C programming language for Linux OS

**UPDATE**

Below is the code fragment I've written so far for listening on one socket. I tried modifying it for listening over two sockets as you've directed but I'm facing trouble while trying to spawn a different thread for the other socket interface. Will it possible for you to modify this to listen on two sockets? It would be really helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *data_processing_thread(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
        int fdmax, listener, newfd, res;
        int optval=1;
        socklen_t addrlen;
        int server_port = 4000;

        /* master, temp file descriptor list */
        fd_set *master, *read_fds;

        /* client, server address */
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
        pthread_t thread;

        master = malloc(sizeof(fd_set));
        read_fds = malloc(sizeof(fd_set));

        FD_ZERO(master);
        FD_ZERO(read_fds);

        /* create endpoint for communication */
        if ((listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
                perror("failed to create listener\n");
                return -1; 
        }
/* check if address is already in use? */
        if (setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval,
                                sizeof(int)) == -1) { 
                perror("socket address already in use!\n");
                return -1;
        }

        /* bind */
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);
        memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

        if (bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr,
                                sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
                perror("failed to do the bind\n");
                return -1;
        }

        /* listen for connect on sockets */
        if (listen(listener, 10) == -1) {
                perror("failed to listen on socket\n");
                return -1;
        }
 /* add the listener to the master set */
        FD_SET(listener, master);
        /* keep track of biggest file descriptor */
        fdmax = listener;

        while (1) {
                read_fds = master;
                /* wait till socket descriptor is ready for the operation */
                if (select(fdmax+1, read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
                        perror("failed to do select() on socket\n");
                        return -1;
                }

                /* Run through existing data connections looking for data to be
                 * read */
                int cnt;
                int *accept_fd = 0;
                for (cnt=0; cnt<=fdmax; cnt++) {
                        if (cnt == listener) {
                                if (FD_ISSET(cnt, read_fds)) {
                                        addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);
                                        if ((newfd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen)) == -1) {
                                                perror("failed to accept incoming connection\n");
                                        } else {
                                                fprintf(stdout, "Server: Connection from client [%s] on socket [%d]\n",
                                                                inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), newfd);

accept_fd = malloc(sizeof(int));
                                                *accept_fd = newfd;

                                                if ((res = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, data_processing_thread, (void*)accept_fd)) != 0) {
                                                        perror("Thread creation failed\n");
                                                        free(accept_fd);
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                                continue;
                        }
                }
        }

        return 1;
}

void *data_processing_thread(void *arg)
{
        int nbytes;
        int *recv_fd = (int*)arg;
        char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);

        while(1) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Server: Waiting for data from socket fd %d\n", *recv_fd);

                /* receive incoming data from comm client */
                if ((nbytes = recv(*recv_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) <= 0) {
                        if (nbytes != 0) {
                                perror("failed to receive\n");
                        }
                        break;
                } else {
                        fprintf(stdout, "Data received: %s\n", buffer);
                }
        }
        close(*recv_fd);
        free(recv_fd);
        pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is a TCP server program example that opens up two different sockets - one for processing data & another for processing management commands. 
I need to keep these two interfaces different. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you test this code? Does it work?

Comment: Yes it does work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create two listening sockets using `socket()`.
2. Bind both to respective address/port using `bind()`.
3. Make both listen using `listen()`.
4. Add both listening sockets to a properly initialised `fd_set` typed variable using `FD_SET()`.
5. Pass the `fd_set` to a call to `select()`
6. Upon `select()`'s return check the reason and perform the appropriate action, typically

   - either calling `accept()` on one of the both listening sockets and add the accepted socket (as returned by `accept()`) to the `fd_set`,
   - or if it's an accepted socket that had triggered `select()` to return, then call `read()`, `write()` or `close()` on it. If `close()`ing the socket also remove it from the `fd_set` using `FD_CLR()`.
7. Start over with step 5.

Important note: The steps above are a rough scheme, not mentioning all possible all traps, so it is absolutly necessary to also read the related man-pages for each step carefully, to understand what is happening.

Comment: I've pasted updated code that listens on one socket. But I'm unable to write the portion of code for listening on the second socket. The problem I'm facing is while from 5th step on-wards for the second socket. Not able to understand how to do select on second socket & how to spawn a separate thread for processing commands received on second socket interface. Please help?

Comment: You don't 'do select on the second socket' at all. You do `select()` on *both* sockets at the same time, by having them both in the `fd_set.` Similarly you select on all the accepted sockets as well, all at the same time. That's what `select()` is for: multiplexed I/O.

Comment: Note that `select()` modifies the `fd_set` that is passed to it, so you must construct a new `fd_set` with relevant sockets every time you call `select()`. To avoid that, you can use `poll()` instead.

Comment: Ok understood. Since I'm listening on all of the available interfaces (using INADDR_ANY) what I did is just spawned a different thread than data_processing_thread() for processing the command for one of the interface out of the available one. It does provided solution to my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know why people ask questions here when they don't use the answers provided.

Comment: Hey, the provided answer has been utilized. The idea of changing from only two interfaces to multiple interface solution suits my application needs better. 

           Advantage:
1. It would be better if I does have multiple interfaces available for processing the data rather than one (& just reserve one interface for command processing)

Comment: No. If you're starting another thread it hasn't been utilized. You only need one thread with `select().` That's its purpose.

Comment: Intention behind adding another thread is to keep command/data processing in separate thread (as I said just to suit application need)

Answer (score 1):

you can bind 0.0.0.0 which means binding all interfaces.
you can't bind two interfaces using only one socket.
you should create a new socket, and bind ti to interface II.